# NoSuchMethodError Table.indexes() hibernate-core-5.2.13.Final.jar when try to start application?

Tags: spring, jpa, websphere

There is application srping+jpa. Webserver is Websphere 8.5.13
So, I launch application by using WebApplicationInitializer where I add configs.

There is problem when added PersisnteceConfig:

```
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"persistence"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"persistence"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "db.hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "db.hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES = "ru.sbrf.risks.services.data.persistence";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String DO_NOT_AUDIT_LOCKING_FIELD = "org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        System.out.println("1");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        System.out.println("2");
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        System.out.println("3");
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES);
        System.out.println("4");
        entityManager.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        System.out.println("5");
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        System.out.println("6");
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        System.out.println("7");
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    //Set properties hibernate
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field",
                env.getRequiredProperty(DO_NOT_AUDIT_LOCKING_FIELD));

        properties.put("verifyServerCertificate", false);
        properties.put("useSSL", false);
        properties.put("requireSSL", false);
        properties.put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", false);
        properties.put("useUnicode", "yes");
        properties.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
        properties.put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
        properties.put("useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift", true);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

So,I use hibernate-core-5.2.13.Final libriary and when try to launch application on WebSphere 8.5.13, I have an error message:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index; (loaded
>   from
>   file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/javax.j2ee.persistence.jar
>   by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@ec08ccb6)
>   called from class org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder (loaded
>   from
>   file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/MyApp_war.ear/MyApp.war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-5.2.13.Final.jar
>   by
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@7f080f2e[war:MyApp_war/MyApp.war]

Comment: Looks like incompatible Versions of javax.persistence and hibernate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javax%2Fpersistence%2FTable.indexes%28%29%5BLjavax%2Fpersistence%2FIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to use a version of Hibernate that implements a different spec version than the JPA 2.0 included in WebSphere 8.5.5. That can be done, but you'll need to bring your own version of the JPA API as well. To do that, you'll either need to switch your web module's class loader to "Parent Last" or move Hibernate and the JPA API jar(s) to a shared library and configure the library to use an isolated class loader (which effectively sets "Parent Last" just for the jars in the library).